# How to share Self-signed TLS certificate between websites

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, webserver, kubernetes-ingress

I've two website within same domain example `app1.test.local` and `app2.test.lcaol`. Below is the procedure using which I've generated the `self-signed` certificate.

- Create a private key.

```sh
openssl genrsa -out tls.key 2048
```

- Edit `openssl.conf` file  and update `req_distinguished_name` and `alt_names` contents.

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = IN
countryName_default = IN
stateOrProvinceName = KA
stateOrProvinceName_default = KA
localityName = Test
localityName_default = Test
organizationalUnitName = test
organizationalUnitName_default = test
commonName = *.test.local
commonName_max = 64
[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.test.local
```

- Create certificate signing request

```sh
openssl req -new -out tls.csr -key tls.key -config openssl.cnf
```

- Sign the SSL Certificate.

```sh
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in tls.csr -signkey tls.key -out tls.crt -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cnf
```

From the `view certificate` option of browser I can see both `SAN` and `CN` has `*.test.local` as the value. However when I launch application `app2` from `app1` browser again prompts for trusting the certificate [`The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.`].

**Question:** How to prevent browser from prompting to `Accept the risk and Continue` multiple times for the same certificate but from different websites for self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to prevent browser from prompting to Accept the risk and Continue multiple times for the same certificate but from different websites for self-signed certificates.

Overriding the warning of a certificate will only affect the currently used domain and not every domain in the certificate. Otherwise somebody could create a certificate for some innocent site but which also includes an SAN of an important site like paypal.com - and later reuse the certificate to impersonate the important site.

To make a certificate trusted for all domains given in the certificate one need to explicitly import the certificate as trusted into the browsers trust store instead of simply ignoring certificate warnings.